# Is Dictionary of ConcurrentQueue threadsafe?

Tags: c#

I am writing log class for my c# program. Multiple threads will be enqueuing data, only one will be dequeuing. Is my code thread safe now or should I use ConcurrentDictionary or ImmutableDictionary?

Keys wont be added/deleted, I'm using only Enqueue and TryDequeue functions.
Which container is the fastest for this kind of work?

```cs
        public static readonly Dictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<string>> Logs = new Dictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<string>>()
        {
            {"Info", new ConcurrentQueue<string>() },
            {"Warn", new ConcurrentQueue<string>() },
            {"Error", new ConcurrentQueue<string>() }
        };

        public static void Add(string type, string content)
        {
            if (type == "Info") Logs["Info"].Enqueue(content);
            else if (type == "Warn") Logs["Warn"].Enqueue(content);
            else if (type == "Error") Logs["Error"].Enqueue(content);
        }

        public static void Save()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //dequeuing and saving data to file
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you never modify the dictionary itself, thread safety of the dictionary doesn't matter.  Thread safety is only an issue with mixed read/write operations.

Comment: Which part of the code you think the problem would be (clearly you know that dictionary is thread safe for read after reading [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) documentation)

Comment: The `Add` method could likely be simpler if you used `Logs.TryGetValue` rather than the `if` and `else if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To signal to other developers that your dictionary is read-only, use `ReadOnlyDictionary<T1, T2>` instead. This prevents you from making changes to the dictionary itself. Since the items in the dictionary are already thread-safe (`ConcurrentQueue`), the rest of your code should be fine.

For example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

...

public static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<string,
    ConcurrentQueue<string>> Logs = CreateLogMap();

...

private static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<string>> CreateLogMap()
{
    var map = new Dictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<string>>()
    {
        {"Info", new ConcurrentQueue<string>() },
        {"Warn", new ConcurrentQueue<string>() },
        {"Error", new ConcurrentQueue<string>() }
    };

    return (new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<string>>(map));
}
```